# ImportError Python cannot import name

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pip, python-2.x

I am trying to reproduce a code from a scientific publication which uses Python 2:
https://github.com/TeamErlich/dna-fountain

The code is based on Python 2 so I had to change my environment to Python 2 from Python 3. Anyways, when I ran the code I realized that Python is not able to import DNAFountain from fountain, although I successfully installed it with `pip install fountain`. I constantly receive this error message:

```html
    File "encode.py", line 9, in <module>
    from fountain import DNAFountain
ImportError: cannot import name DNAFountain
```

Does anybody know why my code is not able to import DNAFountain?

Comment: Is your pip connected to Python 2? What's the output of `pip --version`?

Comment: Can you show the fountain version ? Use the command `pip show fountain`, there may be differences between the versions of the package, and the version for python 2 or 3

Comment: @aasossa (py2) PS C:\teamerlich> pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from C:\Users\aleks\.conda\envs\py2\lib\site-packages\pip (python 2.7)

Comment: @Brinfer the output looks same

Comment: Can you take a look at where your fountain package is installed (usually a miniconda or anaconda subdirectory) and see if you find the location in your path ? `import os; print(os.environ["Path"].split(";"))`. I do not know why this would happen, but maybe your environment variables are not updated to look for packages in the correct folder.

Comment: @SpaceBurger That's interesting. In output I was expection to find the `lib\site-packages` folder but I can't find it. Could this be the reason?

Comment: It is certain that if you add your package folder to your path, you would be able to import it (if you use the correct python version ofc). However, as I wrote just above, I am not certain why your python environement doesn't add it automatically when starting up. This problem happened to a colleague of mine when installing some conda package on his environement using Spyder IDE, but I did not look into the exact reason. Note that depending on how you change your path variable, you may need to restart your console.